# Real-time aware sleep() call?

Tags: c, linux, sleep, clock, suspend

I've written a utility to talk to [TomTom GPS watches over Bluetooth](https://github.com/dlenski/ttblue), and am trying to make it run nicely as a run-and-forget background daemon.

The program periodically communicates with the GPS device and then [`sleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep)s for a while until it's needed again.

I've noticed that `sleep()` interacts strangely with system suspend: when I enter system suspend (laptop running Linux 3.16.0 kernel) and then wake the computer back up, `sleep` doesn't appear to notice the suspend time. For example, take the following `sleep.c`:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    time_t t=time(NULL);
    printf("sleep at: %s", ctime(&t));

    sleep(atoi(argv[1]));

    t=time(NULL);
    printf("wake at: %s", ctime(&t));
}
dlenski@dlenski-ultra:~$
```

Compile, run, and sleep halfway through;

```
$ gcc sleep.c -o sleep
$ ./sleep 30
sleep at: Fri Aug 21 21:05:36 2015
<suspend computer for 17 seconds>
wake at: Fri Aug 21 21:06:23 2015
```

Is there a correct way to suspend program execution in a way that's ***clock-time***-aware rather than ***system-uptime***-aware?

(I've also tried `usleep`, `nanosleep`, and `alarm` and found that they behave similarly.)

**UPDATE:** [`setitimer`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setitimer), as suggested by [@HuStmpHrrr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3040064/hustmphrrr), sounded quite promising... but appears to have the same problem.

This version pauses for more than the requested 30s when I suspend in the middle of it...

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void sighandler() {}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    time_t t=time(NULL);
    printf("sleep at: %s", ctime(&t));

    signal(SIGALRM, sighandler);
    struct itimerval timer = {.it_interval={0,0},
                              .it_value={atoi(argv[1]),0}};
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
    pause();

    t=time(NULL);
    printf("wake at: %s", ctime(&t));
}
```

Comment: what about `alarm`? `alarm() arranges for a SIGALRM signal to be delivered to the calling process in seconds seconds.` reads promising.

Comment: `setitimer` provides more control. you can pass in `ITIMER_REAL` to achieve what you want.

Comment: `setitimer` looked very promising but appears to have the same issue in that it doesn't count "downtime." Polling `time` seems like quite an inelegant solution but possibly the right one :(

Comment: I don't know of one, and after a short search I suspect the most reliable method would be to register with the power management system to be notified on suspend/resume.  Then you'll just have to check your timers on resume (unless you want them to wake the system from suspended state, which is harder).

Comment: For Linux, it's probably worth looking at [`pselect`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pselect). You can set a timeout for periodic returns, wait on 'interesting' events like file (descriptor) activity, as well as signal events. Even if you don't think you need all these features now - you get a much more flexible solution - and your utility looks like something interesting enough that you'll want more features and better response time in the future.

Comment: Thanks all. For the time being, chopping a long interval into 30s chunks and  repeatedly sleeping for `min((real_time-real_start_time), 30s)` seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: Why not use [`timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,..)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html), and set the next expiry in absolute time using [`timer_settime(...,TIMER_ABSTIME,...)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html)? (Or even `CLOCK_REALTIME`, really.) Such a timer should expire immediately after wake-up if the timer expired during suspend. These are all POSIX.1 too, so no Linux-specific/desktop environment shenanigans needed, either.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Many thanks, that works… *if* I use *both* `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `TIMER_ABSTIME`, per [the docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html): "If the value of the CLOCK_REALTIME clock is adjusted while an **absolute timer based on that clock** is armed, then the expiration of the timer will be appropriately adjusted.  Adjustments to the CLOCK_REALTIME clock have **no effect on relative timers** based on that clock." If you want to write an answer, I'll gladly accept it, otherwise I'll add your solution to my answer.

Comment: @DanLenski: Note that `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` isn't adjusted, ever, and its zero epoch is arbitrary, otherwise it's similar to `CLOCK_REALTIME`; that's why the passage you quoted does not apply to it. Because it's never adjusted. However, I haven't **verified** that `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` progresses during suspend, and that both kinds of timers get triggered immediately after resume, so that's why I used conditionals in my comment. You verified it, you answered it. :)

Comment: You're right! `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` appears to behave similarly to `CLOCK_REALTIME` with system suspend. Since it doesn't actually simplify the code, and the documentation isn't clear that this behavior is guaranteed, I'll stick with `CLOCK_REALTIME` for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few solutions and potential solutions:

## Sleep in a loop and check the real elapsed time

There is almost certainly a better way to do it—or there should be!—but here's an acceptable solution for my application for the time being:

- When needing to sleep for a long interval (>30s), I do `sleep(30)` repeatedly, checking that the *real* elapsed time (`time(NULL)-start_time`) is not longer than the total desired pause.
- This way, if the system is suspended for, say, 3 hours, while the desired program pause is 1 hour, the extra delay caused by the suspend will not exceed 30 seconds.

Code to do it:

```
void nullhandler(int signal) {}

int isleep(int seconds, int verbose)
{
    if (verbose) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Sleeping for %d seconds...", seconds);
        fflush(stderr);
    }
    signal(SIGALRM, nullhandler);

    // weird workaround for non-realtime-awareness of sleep:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152276/real-time-aware-sleep-call
    int res=0, elapsed=0;
    for (time_t t=time(NULL); (elapsed<seconds) && (res<=0); elapsed=time(NULL)-t)
        res = sleep((seconds-elapsed > 30) ? 30 : seconds-elapsed);

    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);
    if (res && verbose)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n\n", res ? " woken by signal!" : "");
    return (res>0);
}
```

## Wakeup callback

[@Speed8ump](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2544218/speed8ump) suggested registering a callback for system-wakeup notifications. [This thread over at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/184046/139469) shows how to do it. A good solution, but I'd like to avoid tying my relatively-low-level code too strongly to a particular desktop environment for now.

## `timer_settime`

This is the most elegant and correct solution, in my opinion, and was suggested by [@NominalAnimal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475978/nominal-animal). It uses [`timer_settime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html) and friends from `librt`.

Note that in order to make this work correctly with system suspend, you must use `CLOCK_REALTIME` with `TIMER_ABSTIME`, per the `timer_settime` documentation:

> If the value of the CLOCK_REALTIME clock is adjusted while an absolute
> timer based on that clock is armed, then the expiration of the timer
> will be appropriately adjusted.  Adjustments to the CLOCK_REALTIME
> clock have no effect on relative timers based on that clock.

Here's a demo (link with `librt`, e.g. `gcc -lrt -o sleep sleep.c`):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sighandler(int signal) {}

void isleep(int seconds)
{
    timer_t timerid;
    struct sigevent sev = { .sigev_notify=SIGEV_SIGNAL,
                            .sigev_signo=SIGALRM,
                            .sigev_value=(union sigval){ .sival_ptr = &timerid } };
    signal(SIGALRM, sighandler);
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timerid);

    struct itimerspec its = {.it_interval={0,0}};
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &its.it_value);
    its.it_value.tv_sec += seconds;
    timer_settime(timerid, TIMER_ABSTIME, &its, NULL);
    pause();
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    time_t t=time(NULL);
    printf("sleep at: %s", ctime(&t));

    isleep(atoi(argv[1]));

    t=time(NULL);
    printf("wake at: %s", ctime(&t));
}
```